# I don't understand how to fix this print indentation error

Tags: python

```
name = str(input("Whats your name?: "))
if name is 'Chris':
    print("Hello, " + name)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

So this error shows up right beneath the "t" in `print`. I have tried putting a space after it, like so:

```
print ("Hello, " + name)
```

But that didn't work either. Anyone know what I should be doing differently?

I am using this in the Python command window as opposed to Sublime which I usually use, because it doesn't seem to read the input that is typed in.

Comment: You've got an extra double quote

Comment: Change it to `print ("Hello, " + name)`. Remove the extra quote next to `name`.

Comment: whoops. typing error, not in actual code.

Comment: Umm No! It's actually error in "actual code"

Comment: What python version are you using, 2 or 3?

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? (if the quote is fixed)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I think Python 3.x.

Comment: Using python 3. When i say typing error, i mean when i wrote the question.

Comment: I think only spaces? It indents for me when i press space after a colon

Comment: @ChrisG, good, than you don't have to also worry about `raw_input` and `input`.

Comment: Use == when comparing strings as is compares reference equality. No repro

Comment: Please don't retype code when asking a question. Copy and paste the _actual code_ so we can debug your real problem.

Comment: FWIW, a misplaced quote in that position will not give an indentation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
name = str(input("Whats your name?: "))
if name == 'Chris':
    print("Hello, " + name)
```

You had an extra `"` mark after `name`. Also, you want `==` not `is`; `is` is for determining if two objects are *identical*, meaning, *the literal same object*.

Unless you're doing something more advanced, you'll typically only use `is` to compare with `None`:

```
if variable is None:
    print("No value provided for variable!")
```

Also, make sure that you use the same number of spaces to indent each block of code. If you use 4 spaces, and 3 spaces somewhere else, you'll get an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Thanks, works now. Didn't know about using ==.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Most of the time, you'll only use `is` to compare with `None`.